# How do languages Scala which need covariant return types and "real" class variance run on the CLR?

Tags: c#, types, clr, c#-2.0

The CLR does not support [covariant return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348760/c-covariant-return-types-utilizing-generics) or [full variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-4-0/2734070#2734070) (i. e. applied to classes, not only interfaces and delegates), but there are languages targeting the CLR which use one or both of these features.

Is there some practical workaround for the CLR to enable this functionality or do these languages employ some kind of rewriting/erasure/... technique to fully support their feature set?

Comment: You are mistaken when you say that C++/CLI allows covariant return types. See [Compiler Error C2392](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z1xy8y4.aspx)

Comment: Ok, fixed. Thanks! (Do you know another language with covariant return types?)

Comment: @soc: Native C++ does support them. I expect that's not very relevant or helpful though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably the same way that Java does it (Java 5 supports covariant returns at the language level, but the JVM doesn't support it): by adding synthetic methods. Here's how Java does it: say you have a class like this:

```
class Foo implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    public Foo clone() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes, *two* `clone` methods get generated: `public Foo clone()` (which contains the real code), and `public Object clone()` (which simply returns the result of the former). The latter method (which is synthesised) is how the `clone` method gets to be overridden at the JVM level.

Comment: That sounds likely ... I just wonder why they didn't use that in C# to support that feature then (if it is as easy as it sounds) ...

Comment: @soc: Simply because the C# committee doesn't want to change the specs about it.

Comment: Why do you even need synthetics for this? I imagine a compiler could toss in an implicit cast instead; all the info needed to do this is available at compile time.

Comment: @trinithis: In general, because methods can be called via superclasses, which have the wider return type. In that case, when doing virtual method lookup, the method that is looked up is the one with the same method signature; the method with the covariant return type will not be found. I presume this behaviour (of not finding the covariant override) is for compatibility reasons. If Java had covariant returns since the beginning (so that virtual method lookup considers covariant return types), I'm sure that the synthetic method would not be necessary.