# List<T> to IEnumerable<T> problem in interface

Tags: c#

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
public class Hex
{
    public String terr;
}    

public class HexC : Hex
{
    int Cfield;
}

public interface IHexGrid
{
    IEnumerable<Hex> hexs { get; }
}

public class hexGrid : IHexGrid //error CS0738: 'WpfApplication3.hexGrid' does not               
{
    public List<Hex> hexs { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<HexC> hexList1 = new List<HexC>();
        genmethod(hexList1); //but this compiles fine          
    }

    void genmethod(IEnumerable<Hex> hexList)
    {
        string str1;
        foreach (Hex hex in hexList)
            str1 = hex.terr;            
    }
}
}
```

The full error message is: 'WpfApplication3.hexGrid' does not implement interface member 'WpfApplication3.IHexGrid.hexs'. 'WpfApplication3.hexGrid.hexs' cannot implement 'WpfApplication3.IHexGrid.hexs' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

Why doesn't List implicitly cast to IEnumerable above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no casting involved with property declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Christopher has the right answer, but you could easily work around this by having a private property be the actual list and then the getter on the hexGrid just return the casted IEnumerable interface from the List.

```
public class hexGrid : IHexGrid               
{
    private List<Hex> _hexs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Hex> hexs
    {
       get { return _hexs as IEnumerable; }
       set { _hexs = new List<Hex>( value ); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not need the `as` cast.

Comment: @BoltClock - True, I just added it for clarity.

Comment: Ah thanks, that did the job. I put the set to: set{} as the whole point of IEnumerable is that the collection is effective read only. I wish I'd discovered IEnumerable earlier, its indispensable when working with List<T>

Comment: @RichOliver - In that case you can probably remove the 'set' property altogether if it isn't needed elsewhere.

Comment: No I tried that it complains: error CS0535: 'WpfApplication3.hexGrid' does not implement interface member 'WpfApplication3.IHexGrid.hexs.set'

Comment: @RichOliver - Oh, I mean remove the setter from the interface (assuming you have the ability to change that interface and the change doesn't break other code that needs it).

Comment: Yes my mistake, I realised that just before I read your comment.

Answer (score 6):

That kind of casting (covariance?) doesn't apply to class/interface declarations.  It can only be done on parameters and return types.

The compiler is looking for the exact signature, isn't finding it, and rightly saying you didn't implement the member.  The property/method signature must match exactly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348760/c-covariant-return-types-utilizing-generics/4349584#4349584) actually sums it up better than I could explain.

Comment: Is there any reason for C# not applying covariance to class/interface declarations?

Comment: Cheers, I think I've sort of got it. but I will have to reflect at leisure to fully comprehend the issue.