# subtype and covariant return type

Tags: c#, java

I found an explanation [What is a covariant return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type) but I am no smart to understand it all.

I think Covariant return type theoritically is the type returned by a function that has the same signature with a built-in base class function whose return type is different.

```
class Base{
   TypeX func( int i ){return typex;} // builtin function
};
class Derived:Base{
   TypeY func(int i){return typey;}
}
```

Is my understanding of this so-called covariant return type correct ? [the term really confuses me.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike java, covariant return types are not supported in C#. I believe this is due to the implementation of C# properties, if covariant return types were allowed, the following would be possible:

```
class TypeX { }

class TypeY : TypeX { }

class Base
{
    public virtual TypeX Prop { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override TypeY Prop { get; set; }
}

Derived derived = new Derived();
derived.Prop = new TypeY(); // Valid

Base @base = derived;
@base.Prop = new TypeX(); // Invalid - As this would be using the derived property which should be of TypeY
```

See [Eric Lippert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349584/921321) answer for more information.

Comment: Since a property setter is a function which accepts an input parameter of the property's type, why should one expect to be allowed to override a function so as to require a more specific input parameter?  Personally, I think I'd rather have property getters and setters be entirely separate functions which are tagged to allow property-get or property-set syntax, since there are some cases where it would make sense for property setters to have overloads of types other than the getter's type, but otherwise read-write properties must have invariant types.

Answer (score 6):

This would be an example of covariant return types:

```
class Food {}
class Fruit : Food {}
class FoodEater
{
    public virtual Food GetFavouriteFood() { ... }
}
class FruitEater : FoodEater
{
    public override Fruit GetFavouriteFood() { ... }
}
```

In languages that support return type covariance, this would be legal. That is *a method that returns a Food can be overridden by a method that returns a Fruit, because Fruit is a kind of Food*.  It is called "covariance" because the "variance" is in the *same direction*:

```
A Fruit may be used as a Food, therefore:
A Fruit-returning-method may be used as a Food-returning-method
```

See how the variance is *in the same direction*?

Contrast that with parameter type contravariance:

```
class Food {}
class Fruit : Food {}
class Apple : Fruit {}
class Orange : Fruit {}
class Cake : Food {}
class FruitComparer
{
    public virtual bool Compare(Fruit f1, Fruit f2) { ... }
}
class FoodComparer : FruitComparer
{
    public override bool Compare(Food f1, Food f2) { ... }
}
```

A FruitComparer can compare Apples to Oranges. A FoodComparer can also compare Apples to Oranges, but can compare even more -- it can compare Apples to Cakes, or Cakes to Oranges, or whatever.

In languages that support parameter type contravariance, this is legal. See how the variance directions are now *reversed*:

```
A Fruit may be used as a Food, therefore
A Food-taking-method may be used as a Fruit-taking-method
```

Now the relationship has gone *backwards*, so it is *contravariant*.

C# supports neither kind of method variance *for virtual overloading*. Virtual method overrides must match exactly. However, C# does support both kinds of method variance for *method group to delegate conversions*, and for *generic delegate type conversions*.

Comment: I always forgot which one is contra- and which one is co-variance. Now that you explained the meaning, I might actually remember it. Thanks!

Comment: I always forgot which one is which too, but I try to remember them as: Convariant -> out (shorter word, longer keyword) Contravariant -> in (longer word, shorter keyword)

Comment: @lukas if you spell "covariant" correctly, without an "n", you can also use the mnemonic that associates "co" with "o" and therefor "out", and "contra" with "n" and therefore "in".  This only helps in C# though :-)

Comment: Covariant -> jointly vary -> vary in the same direction (co: jointly, as in cooperate = jointly operate). Contravariant -> oppositely vary -> vary in opposite directions (contra: oppose).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding would be correct if and only if `TypeY` is derived from `TypeX`.

Answer (score 1):

A co-variant return type is a way to return a "narrower" type from a function. The "narrower" type would be the subclass of the original return type.

```
 class A {
 }

 class B extends A {
 }

 // Classes demonstrating method overriding:

 class C {
     A getFoo() {
         return new A();
     }
 }

 class D extends C {
     B getFoo() {
         return new B();
     }
 }
```

The fact that we could return a `B` from `getFoo()` is a co-variant return. Its important to note that while `overriding` you are not allowed to change return type, but with `java 5.0` a co-variant type is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The feature which allows this type of overloading is known as covariant return types *iff* `TypeY` is a subtype of `TypeX`.  Wikipedia has a nice discussion of the feature

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

Answer (score 0):

The ability to use covariant return types in Java is what you've just demonstrated, yes - assuming that `TypeY` is a subclass of `TypeX`. The point is that any callers who only "know" about the signature specified in `Base` are still okay, because any `TypeY` returned by the `Derived` implementation is still a valid `TypeX` reference. Note that it *does* only work for reference types (classes) - it wouldn't be valid to use:

```
// In the base class
long func() { ... }

// In the derived class
@Override int func() { ... }
```

... even though there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, and `int` value isn't *in itself* a `long` value. There isn't the same *representational* validity that there is for references (where a `String` reference *is* an `Object` reference - if you know that a particular set of bits is a `String` reference, you can treat those *exact same bits* as an `Object` reference.).

C# does *not* support covariant return types, but as of C# 4 it *does* support *generic variance* as declared on interfaces and delegates. For example, `IEnumerable<T>` is declared in .NET 4 as

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> { ... }
```

The `out` shows that `T` is *covariant* in the interface, which means this conversion is valid:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;
```

The reverse assignment would *not* be valid, as a sequence of arbirary `object` references may *not* be a valid sequence of `string` references.

For more on this topic, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) (or do a search for c# generic variance).