# C# Interface enforcing property that is another Interface?

Tags: c#, interface, inheritance

Given this code:

```
public interface ITagModel { }

public interface ITemplate {
    ITagModel Model { get; set; }
}

public class EmailTag : ITagModel { }

public class EmailTest : ITemplate {
    public EmailTag Model { get; set; }
}
```

I am being told that the Type of `EmailTag` (inside `EmailClass`) cannot implement the Property `Model` because it is not the type `ITagModel`.

It is inheriting ITagModel....so why won't this work?  What can I do to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# doesn't support [covariant return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4349584/580951).

e.g.

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived : Base { }

public class Component
{
    public virtual Base GetComponent()
    {
        return new Base();
    }
}

public class DerviedComponent : Component
{
    public override Dervied GetComponent()
    {
        return new Derived();
    }
}
```

So you'll need to abstract the return type and constrain it to your interface. That way any implementation will need to supply an `ITagModel`.

```
public interface ITagModel { }

public interface ITemplate<TModel>
    where TModel : ITagModel
{
    TModel Model { get; set; }
}

public class EmailTag : ITagModel { }

public class EmailTest : ITemplate<EmailTag> {
    public EmailTag Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I knew I was having a brain fart.  Been working with Javascript for way too many weeks obviously.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `ITemplate` interface should be generic:

```
public interface ITemplate<TModel> where TModel : ITagModel
{
    TModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public class EmailTest : ITemplate<EmailTag>
{
    public EmailTag Model { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine if your current code worked. I could then write:

```
ITemplate template = new EmailTest();
template.Model = new SomeOtherModel();
```

... and you wouldn't want that. (Basically, you'd be violating type safety.)