# Use local class as a return type from abstract class

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class `Model` which is implemented by `CarModel`.

I want to have a method `Clone` on the `Model` abstract class, which I want to return the type of the instantiating class.

For example, I would like a `CarModel` implementing `Model` to require a `Clone` method that returns `CarModel`, like below:

```
abstract class Model
{
    public abstract Model Clone();
}

class CarModel : Model
{
    public override CarModel Clone() {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work because `Clone` must be of type `Model`. This isn't the outcome I would like, because then a `CarModel` could implement a `Clone` method which actually returns a `BikeModel`.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# covariant return types utilizing generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348760/c-sharp-covariant-return-types-utilizing-generics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your base class generic:

```
abstract class Model<T>
     where T: Model<T>
{
    public abstract T Clone();
}

class CarModel : Model<CarModel>
{
    public override CarModel Clone()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is good practice in C#? I knew that this would work but wasn't sure it was right to pass a class into the generic type for its base class.

Comment: @JamesMonger well, it has two cons 1) you still don't enforce constraint completely and I can write `class HumanModel : Model<CarModel>` 2) it's not easiest thing to understand. But it can help you to specify correct type as return/input type for base class members. Either you deal with base type instead, or you have 1) and 2)