# Override abstract interface property

Tags: c#

Say I have a class like...

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract IAttributes Attributes{ get; set; }
}

public interface IAttributes
{
    string GlobalId { get; set; }
}
```

And a class like this...

```
public class ImplementAttributes : IAttributes
{
    public string GlobalId { get; set; } = "";
    public string LocalId { get; set; } = "";
    // Other Properties and Methods....
}
```

And then I implement it like...

```
public class Derived: Base
{
    public new ImplementAttributes Attributes { get; set; } 
}
```

Now, I realise the above will not work because I can't override the property *Attributes* and if I hide it with *new* then the following bellow is null because the *Base* property does not get written.

```
public void DoSomethingWithAttributes(Base base)
{
    var Foo = FindFoo(base.Attributes.GlobalId);  // Null because its hidden
}
```

But I would like to be able to access the *Base* and *Derived* property attributes eventually like Above.

Can this be accomplished? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want access to both, you either have to hide it (using `new`) or define another interface and explicitly implement it. Otherwise, you always have the option to cast if you know what the runtime type is.

Comment: I updated my question.  I tried new and I think that was the closest to what I am trying to achieve but then when I pass derived objects around as base, then the property is null.

Comment: This does not answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties

Comment: @Alexander Toptygin Are you saying, use the setter in the implemented version of the property to write the value to the base?

Comment: You might want to get familiar with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348760/c-sharp-covariant-return-types-utilizing-generics). Your particular use case isn't using generics but it's the same problem. I'll leave it to you to decide on whether this is a duplicate.

Comment: @BrokenRobot - I think I'm misinterpreting your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T: IAttributes
{
    public abstract T Attributes{ get; set; }
}

public interface IAttributes
{
    string GlobalId { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Derived: Base<ImplementAttributes>
{
    public override ImplementAttributes Attributes { get; set; } 
}
```

And then:

```
public void DoSomethingWithAttributes<T>(Base<T> b) where T : IAttributes
{
    var Foo = FindFoo(b.Attributes.GlobalId);
}
```

You can pass `Derived` instances without specifying a type parameter explicitly:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
DoSomethingWithAttributes(d);
```

Comment: This is a good answer (+1) and I now have a better understanding of generics. However, it introduces a problem of having to pass a type along with my usage of Base. And I would like to be able to simply access the Interface properties regardless of knowing the derived type.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can pass an instance of `Derived` to `DoSomethingWithAttributes` without specifying a type parameter. The type parameter is inferred because `Derived` declares it.

Comment: I don't think you can get around the more verbose declaration of `DoSomethingWithAttributes`, though.

Comment: Ahh, I am beginning to see. Thank you.