# Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<object>' error

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, method-group

I have created the following function:

```
public void DelegatedCall(Action<Object> delegatedMethod)
```

And defined the following method

```
public void foo1(String str) { }
```

However, when I try to call `DelegateCall` with `foo1`:

```
DelegatedCall(foo1);
```

...I get the following compiler error:

> `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<object>'`

What is the reason for this error and how can I correct it? Unfortunately, casting `foo1` to `Action` is not an option.

Comment: Related: [What is a method group in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/1497596)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`DelegatedCall` expects a delegate that takes any `object` as an argument. But your function `foo1` that you are passing to `DelegatedCall` can only cope with a `string` argument. So, the conversion isn't type-safe and thus is not possible.

Input parameters are *[contra-variant](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/contravariance/info)*, but your code needs *[covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/covariance/info)*. (See [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance).)

You can make `DelegatedCall` generic:

```
DelegatedCall<T>(Action<T> action)
```

...or have it take any delegate:

```
DelegatedCall(Delegate action)
```

But then implementing it is ugly and requires reflection. It also doesn't verify that the function has only one parameter at compile-time.

Comment: Are you aware of any way i can create such a code? I want DelegateCall to have the ability to receive a function which receives any one parameter of any type (String, bool, List...)

Comment: Can you recommend on any reading material how to use reflection to implement the second option?

Answer (score 12):

Variance doesn't work that way around; you would need

```
DelegatedCall(obj => foo1((string)obj));
```

As even in 4.0 it won't believe that every object is a string.

Note that if it was `foo1(object)` and `Action<string>` (i.e. the other way around) it probably would work (in 4.0), since every string **is** an object.

Comment: The other way round works even prior to 4.0. When converting from a method group variance was available even in earlier versions.

Comment: Ok is there anyway i can make this work then: I want DelegateCall to have the ability to receive a function which receives any one parameter of any type (String, bool, List...). Any help would be appreciated