# Can't pass method as System.Action windows phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, mono, windows-phone

First of all, we're using unity which means Mono and outdated version of c#

Basically, there's a method called Fire which takes action as a callback. Then you want to pass the method as a callback, and it works perfectly for iOS and Android, but fails to compile for windows phone. Sure I can wrap it with lambda, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work now.

```
void Fire( System.Action callback )
{}

void Method()
{}


Fire( Method ) // works for android and ios, but not for windows phone
Fire( () => Method() ) // compiles everywhere
```

Update: 
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'

Unity 5.3.5p8

Comment: "but fails to compile for windows phone" but I won't post the compile-time error and unity version...

Comment: @Programmer hope it helps :)

Comment: What is `Method`?

Comment: And what windows phone version are you building for? 8.1 SDK? Phone 8.1 SDK? Universal 8.1 SDK? Universal 10 SDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<object>' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704734/cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-system-actionobject-error)

Comment: @Bijan no, there's different problem they are talking about