# generic types polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

```
public class A {}

public class B : A {}
```

now what the best way to get this working

```
List<A> a;
List<B> b = new List<B>();
a = b; // throw Cannot convert List<B> to List<A>
```

Thank you

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `List<T>` type doesn't support covariance, so you can't assign a `List<B>` directly to a `List<A>` even though `B` itself is directly assignable to `A`. You'll need to do a pass through list `b`, converting and adding the items into list `a` as you go. The [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method is a convenient way to do this:

```
List<B> b = new List<B>();
// ...
List<A> a = b.ConvertAll(x => (A)x);
```

Comment: What the behavior difference between ConvertAll(x => (A)x) and Select(x => (A)x) ?

Comment: `ConvertAll` is an instance method on the `List<T>` class and creates a new `List<T>` from the existing list. `Select` is an extension method that acts on any `IEnumerable<T>` and creates a new `IEnumerable<T>` sequence. Using `ConvertAll` should be *slightly* faster than `Select` since it can make some optimisations (for example, it can allocate the target array to the correct length at the outset rather than needing to resize on-the-fly, and it can access the source list's underlying array directly rather than needing to instantiate and use a separate enumerator object).