# covariance/contravariance in C#

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I have a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800963/) that explains contravariance/covariance as follows :

> - a delegate can have more specific parameter types than its method  target. This is called contravariance
> - the return type of a delegate can be less specific than the return type of its target method. This is called covariance

And, this is an example.

```
using System;

delegate void StringAction(string s);
delegate object ObjectRetriever();

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringAction sa = new StringAction(ActionObject);
        sa("hello");

        ObjectRetriever o = new ObjectRetriever(RetrieveString);
        object result = o();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    static string RetrieveString() {return "hello";}

    static void ActionObject(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

I thought in order to use covariance/contravariance, one needs to use `new` as is shown in the example, but I seem to get the same result with `sa = ActionObject` and  `o = RetrieveString`. (I tested with Mono).

- Then, why the writer uses `new` to explain covariance/contravariance?
- What's the theory behind the covariance/contravariance idea? Is it just a fancy name describing `object x = Everything inherit from object`?  Where is this weird name come from? What's the usage for it?

Comment: I find this post pretty useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I have a book that explains contravariance/covariance as follows ...

That is not a very good explanation of variance. It is left completely unclear *precisely what it is* that is called "covariance" and "contravariance".

The thing that actually is variant is never mentioned. The thing that is contravariant is *the mapping from a type to a delegate with a parameter of that type*. Contravariance is a property of *mappings* and *relationships*.

Try reading this and see if you understand it any better:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx

> I thought in order to use covariance/contravariance, one need to use new as is shown in the example, but I seem to get the same result ...

Ever since C# 2.0 you can say either "d = M" or "d = new D(M)" -- the compiler simply recognizes them as two different ways to write the same thing.

> why the writer uses new to explain covariance/contravariance?

I don't know.

> What's the theory behind the covariance/contravariance idea?

The theory is that if you have an *ordering* relationship -- that is, X is bigger than Y if it is legal to say X x = (Y)y -- and you have a *mapping* that *preserves* the ordering relationship, then the mapping is covariant. If it *reverses* the ordering relationship, it is *contravariant*.

For example, suppose Animal is a bigger type than Giraffe. So you can assign an object of type Giraffe to a variable of type Animal.  Animal > Giraffe.

Now make a mapping from a type T to a method M-that-takes-a-T and to a delegate type D-that-takes-a-T.

You can assign a method M-that-takes-an-Animal to a variable of type D-that-takes-a-Giraffe.  D(Giraffe) > M(Animal) but Animal > Giraffe.  The relationship is *reversed*; the *mapping* is *contravariant*.

> Is it just a fancy name describing object x = Everything inherit from object?

No. It is *related* to that concept because object is a *larger type* than almost every other type. But what is actually variant is a *mapping* that preserves or reverses a size relationship.

Try reading this and see if it helps.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

> Where is this weird name come from?

Category theory.

Comment: Unfortunately your blog links no longer work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The best info describing covariance/contravariance in the C# I've ever seen is series of blog posts by Eric Lippert [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/). See starting from the bottom of the list, eleven-parts series.

It is somewhat hard to read sometimes. But it explains everything you could ask in the beginning. :)

It was written prior to actual C# 4.0 implementation, so some discussion of the syntax is obsolete, but everything else seems to be implemented just as described.

Comment: +1 I was just reading through his first few entries on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great wiki article on it: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

It's more a matter of which direction the funnel pours and setting the width of the funnel at an appropriate level...

Answer (score -1):

No idea what you mean in your first question.

The second question can be answered by suggesting looking at casting.  Contravariance is allowing class A which has an extended class B be stored as a class B.

Contravariance

```
class A {
}

class B : public A {
}

B obj = new A();
```

Covariance is allowing class B which extends class A but stored as a class A.

Covariance

```
class A {
}

class B : public A {
}

A obj = new B();
```

Comment: You're plainly wrong. Covariance/contravariance deals with generic types.

Comment: @Suroot : I wanted to ask why the writer uses `ObjectRetriever o = new ObjectRetriever(RetrieveString);` when `ObjectRetrieve o = RetrieveString` works.

Comment: Well, I was probably too harsh. My bad, sorry. In general sense variance is about type orderings. In C# though it mainly associates with generics and delegates. Inherited classes is very trivial case and I didn't think of it as a covariance case at all before :)

Comment: @Ivan One of the implementations is of Generics, but it refers to general conversions of wider -> narrow, narrow -> wider data types.  The main place that I've seen this is in return types.  NOTE: This is not the only case, but (imho) is usually the most widely used form of it.

Comment: Ivan is correct. **What you are describing is absolutely not what variance is.** Assignment compatibility is *the ordering relation* relevant to variance, but what is variant is a *mapping* that *preserves or reverses* that relation. If you want to understand the difference between *assignment compatibility* and *variance*, here's my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

Comment: @Ivan: There are a number of different ways that variance impacts C# and only one of them -- generic type variance -- deals specifically with generic type mappings. The original poster's question is about *variant conversions from method groups to delegates*. C# also has *variant conversions on array types*. Languages like C++ have *return type covariance for virtual method implementations* and some other languages have virtual parameter contravariance. There are lots of ways things can be variant that don't involve generics.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks Eric. I understood my mistake when had taken a look at wiki's definition. And about this particular case: if we treat assignment operator as function of two arguments (informally of course) like `assign(out l, in r)` then it will be covariant on first arg and contravariant on second. It is far-fetched, but seems to be valid, isn't it? Can't be written in C# though due to `out` keyword has not write-only semantic, but nevertheless.

Comment: To not confuse others and be more precise. It's not a function that would be contravariant but rather uplifting mapping from input type `TIn` to function `void assign(TOut l, TIn r)`. Same with covariance. P.S. Not sure it became clearer though... Eric, you definitely have great talent in explaining these kind of things! It seems not-so-hard strictly until you tries to explain to others.

Comment: @Ivan: You're correct; the reason that out parameters are not legal for covariance is because behind the scenes they are actually read-write "ref" parameters. "out" is just a convention of the C# language, not of the actual type system.