# Convert List Type to IEnumerable Interface Type

Tags: c#

I have a

```
List<Person> personlist;
```

How can I convert to

```
IEnumerable<IPerson> iPersonList
```

Person Implements IPerson interface

Comment: `List<T>` is a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: patrickinmpls what are you ultimately trying to do..? can you can try looking up the `Cast` extension method

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're in .NET 4.0 or later, you can just do an implicit cast:

```
IEnumerable<IPerson> iPersonList = personlist;
//or explicit:
var iPersonList = (IEnumerable<IPerson>)personlist;
```

This uses generic contravariance in `IEnumerable<out T>` - i.e. since you only ever get something *out* of an `IEnumerable`, you can implicitly convert `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<U>` if `T : U`. (It also uses that `List<T> : IEnumerable<T>`.)

Otherwise, you have to cast each item using LINQ:

```
var iPersonList = personlist.Cast<IPerson>();
```

Comment: would the normal explicit cast syntax work? Ex: (IEnumerable<IPerson>)personList? If yes/no, then why ?

Comment: @Freeman I've added a bit of an explanation. (And it is relatively new to C#/.NET.)

Comment: @Freeman Whoops, misread. The explicit syntax _would_ work too; you could use `var iPersonList = (IEnumerable<IPerson>)personlist` if you wished.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IEnumerable.Cast`

```
var iPersonList = personlist.Cast<IPerson>();
```

Comment: @ManishSingh You have to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 4.0, you can pass `List<Person>` to a method with a parameter of type `IEnumerable<IPerson>` without implicit or explicit casting.

Implicit casting is done automatically (if possible), thanks to [contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797759/covariance-contravariance-in-c-sharp.)

You can do this:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
// Add items to the list

ProcessPeople(people); // No casting required, implicit cast is done behind the scenes


private void ProcessPeople(IEnumerable<IPerson> people)
{
// Processing comes here
}
```