# Converting list to IEnumerable type

Tags: c#

I have a list of files like this:

```
 List<ProjectFile> projectFilelist =null;
 projectFilelist = projectFileBM.GetAllProjectFileByProjectIdAndPartNum(projectID, string.Empty);
```

The return type in which this code has written is IEnumerable
Now I wanted to retunr this list of projectFileList.

How can I convert this and return?

Comment: look at this SO previous posting on [Converting ListType to IEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071828/convert-list-type-to-ienumerable-interface-type)

Comment: will you only read this data, or will you add/remove/update its elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
projectFileBM.GetAllProjectFileByProjectIdAndPartNum(projectID, string.Empty).ToList()
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

set return type IEnumerable.  List implements the IEnumerable interface so it is already an enumerable.