# AutoMapper throwing 'Sequence contains no elements' (InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm trying to project a list of entities directly from an `IQueryable` using AutoMapper to a dto, however it always seems to fail with an `InvalidOperationException` stating that `The sequence contains no elements`.

**Entity**

```
public class GatewaySetup {

    public static Expression<Func<GatewaySetup, ICollection<Parameter>>
        ParametersAccessor = gateway => gateway.ParametersStorage;

    protected virtual ICollection<Parameter> ParametersStorage { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public IEnumerable<Parameter> Parameters {
        get { return ParametersStorage.AsEnumerable(); } // linq2entities
    }

}
```

**DTO**

```
public class GatewaySetupDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ParameterDto> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GatewaySetup, GatewaySetupDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Parameters, options =>
                                    options.MapFrom(GatewaySetup.ParametersAccessor));
```

**Api**

```
return _repository.Project().To<GatewaySetupDto>();
```

What could be the cause of this? Does AutoMapper fail at the mapping between an `IEnumerable<T>` and a `List<T>`?

Comment: Because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071828/convert-list-type-to-ienumerable-interface-type

Comment: Or possibly the other direction explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617771/converting-from-ienumerable-to-list

Comment: Also, do you have a mapping for `Parameter`/`ParameterDto`?