# Cannot implicitly convert type 'B<A>' to 'B<IA>'?

Tags: c#, autofac, c#-5.0

I am doing a very simple stuff but not working. I have,

```
public class A : IA
{
}

public interface IA
{
}

public class B<T> where T : IA
{

}
```

Now I am using Autofac to register this,

```
        builder.Register<B<IA>>(b =>
        {
            return new B<A>();
        });
```

But I am getting this error,

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'B<A>' to 'B<IA>'?

Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Autofac.IComponentContext,B<IA>>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the classes you're working with, it looks like you'll just want to allow generic arguments to `Register` be determined by the compiler:

```
builder.Register(b => new B<A>());
```

Classes that take a `B<A>` as a dependency, with then get the correct `B<A>` instance. It doesn't make sense for anything to take `B<IA>` as a dependency, generics don't work that way. If that's what you intended to do, you would need to create an interface for `B<T>` instead, which removed any need to specify any generic type.

So:

```
public interface IB
{
}

public class B<T> : IB where T : IA
{

}
```

Then any classes that needed to take a dependency to `B<T>` would actually take a dependency to `IB`.

**Update**

*OpenGenerics* in autofac may also help depending on how you intend to use these classes of yours. Take a look at [the example on their site](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OpenGenerics), which will allows nice control of generic types which are registered through the `RegisterGeneric()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing the feature [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

```
   public class A : IA
   {
   }

   public interface IA<out T>
   {
   }

   public class B where T : IA
   {
   }
```

Related link:

- [Creating Variant with Generics MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)
- [Difference between Covariance and Contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)