# Cannot convert source type 'List<Person>' to IList<ISomething>

Tags: c#, .net, casting

This might be a pretty simple question, but something doesn't make sense to me.

Given this class:

```
public class Person : ICloneable {
    public object Clone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world");
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

Why is this ok?

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { new Person() };

IEnumerable<ICloneable> clonables = people;
```

But this isn't?

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { new Person() };

IList<ICloneable> clonables = people;
```

Why is it I can assign to an IEnumerable IClonable, but not an IList ICloneable?

Comment: The error message you are getting probably already tells you why.

Comment: `IEnumererable<T>` is covariant, which is why that works. `List<T>` is not, and cannot be.

Comment: So, the solution is: `cloneables = people.Cast<ICloneable>().ToList();`

Comment: Not a good solution. You're actually creating a new `List<ICloneable>`, not reassigning the old one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called *covariance*. Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet (among others) gave some nice explanations of covariance (and its twin, *contravariance*) in answers to this question: [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)

**Very basically**, you can enumerate over a list of `Person` just like you would do over a list of `ICloneable`, no problem could occur because you can't change the enumeration. But you can't assign your list of `Person` to a list of `ICloneable` because then you could later try, for example, to insert some other derivative of `ICloneable` in it, which would result in a strong violation of type-safety.

Answer (score 7):

[IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

Notice the `out` in `IEnumerable`? `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I had a different answer, which was wrong.  I apologize.  Thanks Matt for pointing this out.

The error message is quite misleading.  It suggests a cast will work, but does not.  The problem is that the conversion of Person to ICloneable may require adjusting the pointer so that the virtual function table is correct for a generic ICloneable.  That means every element in the list may need an adjustment.  The real fix is to use ToList:

```
        IList<ICloneable> clonablesA = people.ToList<ICloneable>();
```

Ignore some of the comments below, since I completely erased my first answer.

Comment: Don't sign your posts.  They are already signed; see? --------------->

Comment: Even an explicit cast doesn't work.

    IList<ICloneable> cloneables = (IList<ICloneable>)people;

Comment: The error message does not say that an explicit cast exists, nor is one valid in this context.

Comment: Using VS 2013, the error message I see is: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cloneable.Person>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.ICloneable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Ken\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Samples\Cloneable\Cloneable\Program.cs 29 45 Cloneable

Comment: The explicit cast won't work. It will trade your compile time error for a run-time exception (`InvalidCastException`).

Comment: @KC-NH: Where you try to do the cast, obviously.