# How do I make T work with intherited classes?

Tags: c#

I'm programming a dungeon generator for a roguelike. I've a base class called `Room`. It contains methods that can be inherited by other types of rooms. It looks like this but then a little more advanced

```
class Room
{
   protected virtual void Construct() { /*make square room here*/ }
}
class RoundRoom : Room
{
   protected override void Construct() { /*make round room here*/ }
}
```

My class that generates rooms needs to be "fed" with rooms to generate. The room handles the construction, and I've different types of rooms. And I want it to have it that certain specific rooms can be generated based on some conditions or chances.

So I feed it with different types of rooms. First I thought of this:

```
    class RoomEntry
    {
        public Point chance;
        public Room room;
    }
```

And then have an array of it

```
RoomEntry[] entries;
```

And then just feed it

```
Generator.Feed(entries[random.Next(0, 10)].room); // just an example
```

But that won't work! If I edit the room in the generator, It'll change in `RoomEntry` too! And I need to use it quite a few times!
So if I would make *new* rooms based on some room type... It'll work!

So I came up with this:

```
class RoomPlanner
{
    class RoomEntry<T> where T : Room, new()
    {
        public Point chance;
        T r;

        public Room RoomToBuild()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    RoomEntry<Room>[] entrys;

    public void Foo()
    {
        entrys = new RoomEntry<Room>[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < entrys.Length; i++)
        {
            entrys[i] = new RoomEntry<RoundRoom>();
        }
    }
}
```

But that's not possible. I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Super_ForeverAloneInThaDungeon.RoomPlanner.RoomEntry<Super_ForeverAloneInThaDungeon.RoundRoom>' to 'Super_ForeverAloneInThaDungeon.RoomPlanner.RoomEntry<Super_ForeverAloneInThaDungeon.Room>'
```

So, how do can I make it accept classes that inherit from `Room`, or how do I take a different approach to this problem?

It's not an duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551). That's a different problem, and I do not have enough information to fix my problem entirely out of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance

Comment: @Jonny, `out` can only be used on `interface` types.

Comment: How about making `Room` an interface type instead? Then you can add `where T : IRoom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that covariant/contravariant type parameters can only be used with interface or delegate types.  (More information on that in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)  Essentially, there is no way to declare a `RoomEntry<T>` that is contravariant with `RoomEntry<Room>`, even with the constraint that `T : room`.

You could get around this by defining an `IRoomEntry` interface that is implemented by `RoomEntry<T>`, like this:

```
interface IRoomEntry
{
    Room RoomToBuild();
}

class RoomPlanner
{
    class RoomEntry<T> : IRoomEntry
        where T : Room, new()
    {
        public Point chance;
        T r;

        public Room RoomToBuild()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

    IRoomEntry[] entrys;

    public void Foo()
    {
        entrys = new IRoomEntry[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < entrys.Length; i++)
        {
            entrys[i] = new RoomEntry<RoundRoom>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! The only thing that breaks is the variables. `IRoomEntry` doesn't have `Point chance`, so you have to cast it, but that's impossible.
Make `Point chance` a property instead will work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just want to `Clone` the room before feeding it to the `Generator`. You could just add a `Clone` method to your `Room` class:

```
Room Clone() { return (Room)this.MemberwiseClone(); }
```

And then feed it like so:

```
Generator.Feed(entries[random.Next(0, 10)].room.Clone());
```

Comment: I like your approach, it's not a direct solution to the problem, but it may be actually a better one.

Comment: Be careful with too many objects with just copying stuff around. It would be better to try to use some Value Types if you go towards cloning.

Comment: @GeorgeOnofrei Of course, this also depends on how the values are actually used. I assume this is only used while generating the "dungeon", so there is a fixed amount of rooms being created, and those rooms are there to stay. Value-types aren't a silver bullet either - you really only want to use them for "a bunch of values" kind of objects; implementing interfaces is tricky (you just lost that "not on the heap, maybe" part), you lose inheritance, and it's a pretty good idea to avoid mutable structs as well.