# C# Generics, interfaces and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics

I've two interfaces:

```
public interface IAmA
{
}

public interface IAmB<T> where T : IAmA
{
}
```

And two classes implementing these interfaces like this:

```
public class ClassA : IAmA
{
}

public class ClassB : IAmB<ClassA>
{
}
```

When trying to use these classes as shown:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        var list = new List<IAmB<IAmA>>();
        list.Add(new ClassB());
    }
}
```

I get this compiler error:

`cannot convert from 'ClassB' to 'IAmB<IAmA>'`

I know I can make the compiler happy using:

```
public class ClassB : IAmB<IAmA>
{
}
```

But I need to be able to be the Type parameter for `IAmB<>` in `ClassB` an implementation of `IAmA`.

Comment: What does "pass an implementation of IAmA" mean? ClassB does *not* inherit anything from ClassA, it still has to implement every member of IAmB. Why do you *have* to inherit from IAmB<ClassA> instead of IAmB<IAmA> ? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: the update didn't explain anything - it's clear from the start you want to use the concrete class - the question is *why*?

Comment: While you can declare T as a covariant parameter (out T), you will only be able to use it in return parameters. *What is the actual problem you are trying to solve*?

Comment: Well, duh - `ClassB` is *not* `IAmB<IAmA>`. Why would you want to treat it that way? Do you think it would be reasonable if you could just implicitly pass an `object` as a `string` argument to a method? Because that's exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks to your question `why?` I noticed that I don't need a generic Type parameter for `IAmB` at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick answer is that you *can* do what you ask by declaring the type parameter of `IAmB<T>` as covariant, **only if the type is used as a return type**:

```
public interface IAmB<out T> where T : IAmA
{
    T SomeMethod(string someparam);
}
```

`out T` means that you can use a more specific type than then one specified in the constraints.

You won't be able to use T as a parameter. The following won't compile:

```
public interface IAmB<out T> where T : IAmA
{
    void SomeMethod(T someparam);
}
```

From the documentation

> You can use a covariant type parameter as the return value of a method that belongs to an interface, or as the return type of a delegate. You cannot use a covariant type parameter as a generic type constraint for interface methods.

*This isn't a compiler quirk.* 
Assuming you could declare a covariant method parameter, your list would end up containing some objects that *couldn't* handle an `IAmB<IAmA>` parameter - they would expect an input of ClassA or more specific. Your code would compile but fail at runtime.

Which begs the question - why do you want to use `IAmB<ClassA>` ?

You should think about before using this though, as there may be *other*, more suitable ways to address your actual problem. It's unusual to use a generic interface implementing a concrete type but trying to use it as if it were implementing another interface.

You can check the MSDN documentation's section on [Covariance and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) as well as Eric Lippert's an Jon Skeet's answers to [this SO question: Difference between Covariance and Contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)

Answer (score 3):

Fast answer : make the generic type covariant (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)) in your interface

```
public interface IAmB<out T> where T : IAmA
{
}
```

this will resolve the compiler problem.

But this won't answer the `why` asked by Panagiotis Kanavos !

Answer (score 2):

The trick is making the type constraint `T` on `IAmB<T>` *covariant*, with the `out` keyword:

```
public interface IAmB<out T> where T : IAmA
{
}
```

This allows you to use a more specific type than originally specified, in this case allowing you to assign an `IAmB<ClassA>` to a variable of type `IAmB<IAmA>`.

For more information, see [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I just tell why this error reported.

if your `IAmB` has a method

```
public interface IAmB<T> where T : IAmA
{
    void foo(T p);
}

public class ClassB : IAmB<ClassA>
{
    void foo(ClassA p)
    {
        p.someIntField++;
    }
}
```

and we have another class

```
public class ClassC : IAmB<ClassA2>
{
    void foo(ClassA2 p)
    {
        p.someOtherIntField++;
    }
}
```

and we assume `List<IAmB<IAmA>>.Add(T p)` implement like this

```
IAmA mParam = xxxx;
void Add(IAmB<IAmA>> p){
    p.foo(mParam);
}
```

thinking all compile OK. you pass a ClassB instance to `List.Add`, it becomes

```
void Add(IAmB<IAmA>> p){
    //p is ClassB now
    p.foo(mParam);//COMPILER CAN NOT MAKE SURE mParam fit ClassB.foo
}
```

Comment: This isn't an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using Contravariance and Covariance.

```
public interface IAmA
{
}

**public interface IAmB<out T> where T : IAmA
{
}**


public class ClassA : IAmA
{
}

public class ClassB : IAmB<ClassA>
{
}


public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        var list = new List<IAmB<IAmA>>();
        **list.Add(new ClassB());**
    }
}
```

Now you don't get compiler error. Compiler is happy.

Comment: Not quite - covariance only allows T to be used as a return type.