# Override a method (return type DBDataReader) and return a different type(SQLDBDataReader)

Tags: c#, database

I am currently implementing a small software that could read data from different DataBases. The followin is the code:

```
interface Fetch
{
    Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> GetData();
}

abstract class Conn : Fetch
{ 
    abstract public void Connect();
    abstract public Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader> GetData();
}

class SqlConn : Conn 
{
    public override void Connect() 
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        try
        {
            _connection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException dbe)
        {
            throw dbe;
        }
    }
    public override Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader> GetData()
    {
        using (_connection)
        {
            Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader>();
            _xmlDoc.Load("Queries.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = _xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//query");
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                _command = new SqlCommand(iterator.Current.ToString());
                _command.Connection = _connection;
                _command.CommandText = iterator.Current.ToString();
                SqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader() as SqlDataReader;

                dataDictionary.Add(iterator.Current.GetAttribute("name", ""), reader);
            }
            return dataDictionary;
        }
    }
}

class OraConn : Conn 
{
    public override void Connect()
    {
        _connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
    }
    public override Dictionary<string, OracleDataReader> GetData()
    {
       using (_connection)
        {
            Dictionary<string, OracleDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, OracleDataReader>();
            _xmlDoc.Load("Queries.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = _xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//query");
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                _command = new OracleCommand(iterator.Current.ToString());
                _command.Connection = _connection;
                _command.CommandText = iterator.Current.ToString();
                OracleDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader() as OracleDataReader;

                dataDictionary.Add(iterator.Current.GetAttribute("name", ""), reader);
            }

            return dataDictionary; 
        }
    }
}
```

But My problem is the return type, SQLDataReader and OraDataReader in the derived class.
This causes a compiler error that states

> ‘Error    2   'DashBoard.Connection.OraConn.GetData()': return type must be 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to match overridden member 'DashBoard.Connection.Conn.GetData()
>   ’.

How can I solve this problem? Or is there other ways to implement this funtion?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to change method signature at all?

Comment: Because in the function, I will do some excutions with SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, and the return value is of type Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature has to stay the same, but as long as your sub-classes inherit from `DbDataReader` you can return other `DbDataReader` types such as `SqlDataReader` and it will compile.

for example:

```
abstract class DbDataReader
{
    // ...
}

class SqlDataReader : DbDataReader
{
}

// ...

class SqlConn : Conn 
{
    public override Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> GetData()
    {
       return new Dictionary<string, DbDataReader>
       {
            { "Key", new SqlDataReader() } 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you! I am a beginner of C#,and I am not quite clear about the code. Can I use Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader>() in the function GetData,  and use dataDictionary as the return value??

Comment: Try it, if the compiler says no, then you can't. It's to do with variance, have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance but it can take a bit to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
public interface IValue<T> { T GetValue(); }
public class SomeClass : IValue<DbDataReader>, IValue<SqlDataReader>
{
    DbDataReader IValue<DbDataReader>.GetValue() { return objDbDataReader; }
    SqlDataReader IValue<SqlDataReader>.GetValue() { return objSqlDataReader; }
}
```