# Returns DbDataReader when SqlDataCommand.ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, database

I am writing a function to read data from sql database, the function is as follows,

```
public override Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> GetData()
{
    using (_connection)
    {
        Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, DbDataReader>();
        _xmlDoc.Load("Queries.xml");
        XPathNavigator navigator = _xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//query");
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            _command = new SqlCommand(iterator.Current.ToString());
            _command.Connection = _connection;
            _command.CommandText = iterator.Current.ToString();
            SqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

            dataDictionary.Add(iterator.Current.GetAttribute("name", ""), reader);
        }
        return dataDictionary;
    }
}
```

But I get a complier error, stating:

> Cannot convert source type 'system.data.common.dbdatareader' to target
>   type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader '

But I check the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Where it says that the return type of ExecuteReader() is 'system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader'

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code replace DbDataReader to IDataReader..

```
public Dictionary<string, IDataReader> GetData()
    {
        using (_connection)
        {
            Dictionary<string, IDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IDataReader>();
            _xmlDoc.Load("Queries.xml");
            XPathNavigator navigator = _xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//query");
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                _command = new SqlCommand(iterator.Current.ToString());
                _command.Connection = _connection;
                _command.CommandText = iterator.Current.ToString();
                IDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

                dataDictionary.Add(iterator.Current.GetAttribute("name", ""), reader);
            }
            return dataDictionary;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is looking for a return type of `Dictionary<string, DbDataReader>` but you are returning `Dictionary<string, SqlDataReader>`.

```
public override Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> GetData()
{
    using (_connection)
    {
         Dictionary<string, DbDataReader> dataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, DbDataReader>();
         xmlDoc.Load("Queries.xml");
         XPathNavigator navigator = _xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
         XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("//query");
         while (iterator.MoveNext())
         {
             DbCommand _command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(iterator.Current.ToString());
             IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(_command);

              dataDictionary.Add(iterator.Current.GetAttribute("name", ""), dataReader);
         }
         return dataDictionary;
   }
}
```

Comment: Even I changed the signature, this error still exists. And the reason why I use this signature is because I want to override a base function, so that I can do the same executions with sql and oracle databases.                               Like stated in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341435/override-a-method-return-type-dbdatareader-and-return-a-different-typesqldbda

Comment: I didn't notice you were overriding a method. So basically then you can't add the SqlDataReader to dictionary like you are in the while loop. It would have to be a DbDataReader.

Comment: I made an update to the code. That should return you the proper type.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the type of db?

Comment: It's of type Database db. It's like your SqlConnection class. You may just be able to use SqlConnection and SqlCommand still and just use the IDataReader to read the sql command.