# C# generics: list of interface-implementing objects

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to understand some specifics about C#'s generics.

If I have a method defined as such

```
 public static void AssertContains<T>(IEquatable<T> val, List<IEquatable<T>> optionsObjs, XML xml, string context)
```

and a class that implements `IEquatable`,

```
public class Tag : IEquatable<Tag>
{
    public string id;
    public bool Equals(Tag other)
    {
        return other.id == this.id;
    }
}
```

why is the following invalid?

```
AssertContains(aTag, aListOfTags, el, "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `List<T>` isn't **covariant**, so you cant convert `List<Type>` to `List<BaseType>`.

In your case `List<Tag>` and `List<IEquatable<Tag>>`.

You can fix this changing `optionsObjs` parameter type to `IEnumerable<IEquatable<T>>`:

```
public static void AssertContains<T>(IEquatable<T> val, 
                                     IEnumerable<IEquatable<T>> optionsObjs,
                                     XML xml,
                                     string context)
```

Thats because `IEnumerable<T>` is **covariant**, so you can do things like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEquatable<Tag>> list = new List<Tag>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is asked in some form almost every day.

A list of animals may not be used in any context in which a list of giraffes is needed.  Why?  Because a list of animals might contain a tiger.

A list of giraffes may not be used in any context in which a list of animals is needed. Why? Because a list of animals might have a tiger inserted into it, and now you've inserted a tiger into what is actually a list of giraffes.

However, a *sequence* -- `IEnumerable<T>` -- of giraffes may be used as a sequence of animals. Why is this legal, when it is illegal to do so with lists?  Because sequences have no method that allows you to add a tiger to a sequence of animals.

Do a search on this site or the internet for "covariance and contravariance in C#" and you will find lots of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work because of [contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx); basically, a `List<Derived>` cannot be treated as a `List<Base>`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that defining the method as

```
public static void AssertContains<T>(T val, List<T> optionsObjs, XML xml, string context) where T: IEquatable<T>
```

makes `AssertContains(aTag, aListOfTags, el, "");` valid.

However, if someone can explain why my original post was wrong, I'll accept their answer.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in `List<IEquatable<T>>` because it is generic in generic. While using the below statement you avoid that generic-in-generic problem.

```
public static void AssertContains<T>(T val, List<T> optionsObjs, XML xml, string context) where T: IEquatable<T>
```

In order to demonstrate you that below I wrote it using 2 generic types:

```
public static void AssertContains<T, Z>(IEquatable<T> val, List<Z> optionsObjs, XML xml, string context) where Z : IEquatable<T>
```

That works out the same way, but taking a careful look leads us to the above statement, because `IEquatable<T> val` may be replaced by `Z val`. So the 2 generic types are useful if you had a generic parameter:

```
public static void AssertContains<T, Z>(T anotherValue, IEquatable<T> val, List<Z> optionsObjs, XML xml, string context) where Z : IEquatable<T>
```