# Generics wildcard or something of the sort

Tags: c#, generics

Currently doing an assignment where I have to create a custom user control implemented in C#. I mainly have a java background so I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible in C# - if it isn't, could someone please provide me a link or alternative way I can accomplish the same thing in C#.

```
public abstract class Graph<T,U>
where T : Configuration.GraphConfiguration
where U : Representatives.GraphRepresentative
{
    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}

public class LineGraph: Graph<LineGraphConfiguration,LineGraphRepresentative>{

    public void draw(Graphics g){

    } 

}

//"Graph" is not valid since the type params <T,U> are not specified..
//However, I cannot supply them since I don't know until runtime what 
//they are. In java just "Graph" or Graph<?,?> would be valid and I  need
//something similar.
public class MyCustomControl: UserControl{
    Graph currentGraph;

    override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
       currentGraph.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

So basically I need a type or some kind of way of holding both a LineGraph and any other type of Graph - for example later a BarGraph - even if the type params are not the same.

Comment: In Java, generics are syntactic sugar. In C#, they're a compile-time concern :D

Comment: Yep, generics work completely different in C#. In C#, there is no class `Graph`, while in Java, there is *only* the class `Graph`.

Comment: Haha I figured they weren't the same, unfortunately I figured out a little to late though.. after I had finished the implementations of the classes. Is there an alternative I can use? Little confused as to why it doesn't just deduce to a Graph<GraphConfiguration,GraphRepresentation> though, since that makes sense to me.

Comment: @Eladian Yes, interfaces. Check my answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your code shows that you don't need these generic types to draw the whole graph, I see that you can easily solve the issue defining a non-generic interface:

```
public interface IGraph
{
     void Draw(Graphics g);
}
```

...and your abstract class can implement it:

```
public abstract class Graph<T,U> : IGraph
where T : Configuration.GraphConfiguration
where U : Representatives.GraphRepresentative
{
    public abstract void Draw(Graphics g);
}
```

...so this means that you can now use `IGraph` to type your class field:

```
public class MyCustomControl: UserControl{
    IGraph currentGraph;

    override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
       currentGraph.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

### About generics, wildcards...

In .NET, at least, generics were introduced to enforce strong typing as much as possible, and avoid a lot of *casts* that hurt performance and maintainability. It's not something that can be *by-passed*.

BTW, C# has *covariance* and contravariance on interfaces and delegates. I suggest you that you take a look at the following resources:

- [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).
- [Generics in the Run Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx)
- [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)

Comment: I have to improve my typing skill :) You were faster:)

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser I don't type quickly. The keyboard types because my mind has some thought....

Comment: Duh! Didn't even think of that. Probably because Iv'e never come across having to do it before! This makes sense though, thanks!