# Parameter must be input-safe error

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

Here is a piece of my code:

```
public interface IA<in TInput>
{
    void Method(IB<TInput> entities);
}

public interface IB<in T> { }
```

I can't figure out why I get following compile error:
"Parameter must be input-safe. Invalid variance: The type parameter |TInput| must be contravariantly valid on "IB< in T>".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designator of contravariance in C# (i.e. `in`) is intuitive only at the immediate level, when you make a method that "takes in" a parameter of generic type. Internally, however, contravariance means an *inversion* of a relation ([Q&A with an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202349/335858)) so using `in` inside `IA` makes it incompatible with `IB`.

The problem is best illustrated with an example. Consider class `Animal` and its derived class `Tiger`. Let's also assume that `IB<T>` has a method `void MethodB(T input)`, which is called from `IA`'s `Method`:

```
class A_Impl<T> : IA<T> {
    T data;
    public void Method(IB<TInput> entities) {
        entities.MethodB(data);
    }
}
```

Declaring `IA<in TInput>` and `IB<in TInput>` means that you can do

```
IA<Animal> aForAnimals = new A_Impl<Animal>();
IA<Tiger> aForTigers = aForAnimals;
```

`IA<in TInput>` has a method that takes `IB<TInput>`, which we can call like this:

```
aForTigers.Method(new B_Impl<Tiger>());
```

This is a problem, because now `A_Impl<Animal>` passes an `Animal` to `MethodB` of an interface that expects a `Tiger`.

You would have no problem with `IB<out T>`, though - both with covariance and contravariance:

```
public interface IB<out T> {
//                  ^^^
}
// This works
public interface IA<in TInput> {
    void Method(IB<TInput> x);
}
// This works too
public interface IC<out TInput> {
    void Method(IB<TInput> x);
}
```