# How to register Generic Interfaces with a Interface Type in AutoFac?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, autofac

I'm trying to register a Generic Interface with multiple Types using Autofac and I like to call:

```
container.Resolve<Enumerable<IGenericInterface<IInterface>>>();
```

To resolve all the Implementations of IGenericInterface with a type of IInterface.

I already tried to register the concrete classes that have the generic interface with a concrete class as generic interface with the Interface:

```
builder.Register(r => new TalkToMeLoud())
    .As<IGenericInterface<Hello>>()
    .As<IGenericInterface<Bye>>()
    .As<IGenericInterface<IInterface>>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

But this will throw an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: The type 'TestConsoleApp.TalkToMeLoud' is not assignable to service 'TestConsoleApp.IGenericInterface`1[[TestConsoleApp.IInterface, TestConsoleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Because this is part of a migration from Unity to Autofac I know this can be done by Unity like this:

```
Container.ResolveAll(typeof(IGenericInterface<IInterface>))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

PS: This is my [testproject](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNnG3Q7E1xhOUN2bVhpOWtva0E/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is quite clear:

> The type 'TalkToMeLoud' is not assignable to service 'IGenericInterface'.

In other words, you will either have to:

- Implement `IGenericInterface<IInterface>` on `TalkToMeLoud` or
- Make `IGenericInterface<T>` covariant by setting `T` as `out` argument. i.e. `IGenericInterface<out T>`.

The CLR will not be able to cast `TalkToMeLoud` to `IGenericInterface<IInterface>` even though it might implement `IGenericInterface<Hello>` where `Hello` implements `IInterface`. If your not familiar with the concept of variance, you might want do a little google search and read answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance).

So in your case you probably need to make your interface covarant; this allows you to cast from `IGenericInterface<Hello>` to `IGenericInterface<IInterface>`. This only works however when `T` is only used as output argument in the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the information this is helpfull for me, but do you know why Unity can resolve all the implmentations with IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<IInterface>> and autofac can't?

Comment: @donlobbo: If `IGenericInterface<T>` is not variant, the list that Unity returns should be empty. If not, please update your question to show: 1. your interface definition, 2. your unity configuration 3. which implementations are resolved when you resolve that enumerable and 4 the definition of those implementations.