# ObservableCollection with generic type does not work

Tags: c#

I do not know if I understood something wrong. But Visual Studio says that adding an item does not allow the conversion from `ExporterTaskWorker<ExporterTypeMusic>` to `ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType>`. But ExporterTypeMusic implements the IExporterType interface.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public interface IExporterType
{
    bool BrandChannelAssigning();
}

public class ExporterTypeMusic : IExporterType
{
    public bool BrandChannelAssigning()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ExporterTaskWorker<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : IExporterType
{
    public Config TheConfig { get; set; }

    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
    ...
    ...

    public ExporterTaskWorker(Config _config) {

    }
}



public class SomeClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType>> ExporterInstanceCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType>>();

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Config theConfig = new Config();
        ExporterTaskWorker<ExporterTypeMusic> exporterTaskWorker = new ExporterTaskWorker<ExporterTypeMusic>(theConfig);

        ExporterInstanceCollection.Add(exporterTaskWorker);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do something like this? `ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType> exporterTaskWorker = new ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType>();`

Comment: This behaviour is know as contravariance. The accepted answer explains why what you are trying to do is not allowed with Generics. (see link below)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance)

Comment: @Nik - That's not a duplicate. It's certainly related to this question, but an answer to the linked question would not be able to be dropped in here as an answer.

Comment: @Marcus - Just because `ExporterTypeMusic` is-a `IExporterType` it does not mean that `ExporterTaskWorker<ExporterTypeMusic>` is-a `ExporterTaskWorker<IExporterType>`. It is not.

Comment: Ok. Strange thing