# A little bit confusion with C# Generics, T, Abstraction ?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, generics, abstraction

I am a C# game maker with Unity. I have collectable management system.

CollectableManager

```
public List<CollectableParent<Collectable>> collactableParentsList;
```

CollectableParent

```
public class CollectableParent<T> : CollectableRelatedMonoBehaviour where T : Collectable
```

SpawnPointDefinedCollectableParent

```
public class SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<T> : CollectableParent<T> where T : Collectable
```

Collectable

```
public abstract class Collectable : CollectableRelatedMonoBehaviour, IHasPlayableSound
```

Collectable_Money

```
public class Collectable_Money : Collectable
```

CollectableParent_Money

```
public class CollectableParent_Money : SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<Collectable_Money>
```

**PROBLEM**

"collactableParentsList" in CollectableManager does not accept `SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<Collectable_Money>` as item when T is defined as "Collectable_Money", it is derived from "Collectable". If I do this `SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<Collectable>`, it is accepted as item into list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that even though `Collectable_Money` is a sub-class of `Collectable`, that does *not* make `SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<Collectable_Money>` a sub-class of `CollectableParent<Collectable>`.

It may be possible to fix this by using generic interfaces. If we change `CollectableParent<T>` to be an interface, and define it to be **covariant** in `T` via the `out` modifier. (You haven't provided the definition for `CollectableRelatedMonoBehaviour`, but it will also need to be converted to an interface):

```
public interface ICollectableParent<out T> : ICollectableRelatedMonoBehaviour where T : Collectable
```

If you then define the list as:

```
public static List<ICollectableParent<Collectable>> collectableParentsList;
```

Then you can successfully add items of type `SpawnPointParentDefinedCollectableParent<Collectable_Money>` to it.

The critical part here is that the `ICollectableParent<T>` interface is covariant in `T`. This makes it possible to pass an instance that implements `ICollectableParent<Collectable_Money>` where an `ICollectableParent<Collectable>` is expected.

Defining the interface as covariant in `T` does introduce some restrictions, specifically (and as implied by the `out` modifier used to indicate covariance), the type `T` must only be used as a return value on the interface's methods. For example:

```
public interface ICollectableParent<out T> : ICollectableRelatedMonoBehaviour where T : Collectable
{
    // This is allowed - T is used as a return type
    T GetChild();
    // This is *not* allowed - T is used as a parameter
    void SetChild(T child);
}
```

You can read more about covariance, and its inverse (contravariance) here: [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance/2202349#2202349)

Comment: Thank you for great answer, the limitation of void SetChild(T child) really effected me, I propably rethink whole design again, it looks like generics limits me in this case.