# How can I add a type invariant setter to a covariant interface?

Tags: c#, covariance

I have a type Shelter that needs to be covariant, so that an override in another class* can return a `Shelter<Cat>` where a `Shelter<Animal>` is expected. Since classes cannot be co- or contravariant in C#, I added an interface:

```
public interface IShelter<out AnimalType>
{
    AnimalType Contents { get; }
}
```

However, there is a place where an IShelter (compile-time type) is assigned a new animal, where we know for sure that the animal being set is going to be a Cat. At first, I thought I could just add a set to the Contents property and do:

```
IShelter<Cat> shelter = new Shelter(new Cat());
shelter.Contents = new Cat();
```

But adding the setter is not possible;

```
Error   CS1961  Invalid variance: The type parameter 'AnimalType' must be invariantly valid on 'IShelter<AnimalType>.Contents'. 'AnimalType' is covariant.
```

This makes sense, because otherwise I could pass the catshelter to this function:

```
private static void UseShelter(IShelter<Animal> s)
{
    s.Contents = new Lion();
}
```

However, I'm not going to do that. It would be nice to have some way to mark the setter as invariant so that the UseShelter function would only be able to assign an Animal, and so that this would be enforced at compile-time. The reason I need this is because there is a place in my code that knows it has a `Shelter<Cat>`, and needs to re-assign the Contents property to a new Cat.

The workaround I found so far is to add a jucky runtime type check in an explicit set function; Juck!

```
public void SetContents(object newContents)
{
    if (newContents.GetType() != typeof(AnimalType))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SetContents must be given the correct AnimalType");
    }
    Contents = (AnimalType)newContents;
}
```

The parameter needs to be of type object, so that this function can be specified in the interface. Is there any way to enforce this at compile-time?

* To clarify, there is a function: `public virtual IShelter<Animal> GetAnimalShelter()` that is overridden and returns an `IShelter<Cat>`:

```
public override IShelter<Animal> GetAnimalShelter(){
    return new Shelter<Cat>(new Cat());
}
```

A minimal working example including most of the code above follows:

```
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Lion : Animal { }

public interface IShelter<out AnimalType>
{
    AnimalType Contents { get; }

    void SetContents(object newContents);
}

class Shelter<AnimalType> : IShelter<AnimalType>
{
    public Shelter(AnimalType animal)
    {
    }

    public void SetContents(object newContents)
    {
        if (newContents.GetType() != typeof(AnimalType))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("SetContents must be given the correct AnimalType");
        }
        Contents = (AnimalType)newContents;
    }

    public AnimalType Contents { get; set; }
}

class Usage
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IShelter<Cat> catshelter = new Shelter<Cat>(new Cat());
        catshelter.SetContents(new Cat());
        catshelter.SetContents(new Lion()); // should be disallowed by the compiler
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here, but shouldn't a simple `{get; set;}` do the trick here? I mean, the type of the property is `Cat`...

Comment: "..override in another class can return a Shelter where a Shelter is expected" .. I don't understand this requirement. Could you give an example?

Comment: @marsze look at it now... as it wasnt wrapped in code ticks the angle braces were ignored

Comment: "However, I'm not going to do that." <-- The compiler ensures you **cannot** do that, not just that you promise not to.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that's true, but it enforces more than is necessary. The question is, how to allow a Cat to be reassigned, but not subtypes of Cat - because the shelter is covariant, that may go down a sibling path of the inheritance tree and become incorrect.

Comment: There is no way to declare this, you will have to enforce it at runtime. The problem here is that you're looking for a concept that doesn't exist *as such* in C#, you want to enforce exactly which type to allow without the possibility of inheritance. You can't do that. Either you declare your interface to be `in`, in which case you can cast the interface to a `<T2>` where `T2` is either `T` or a descendant of `T`, or you declare it to be `out` in which case you can cast it to a `<T2>` where `T2` is either `T` or a base class of `T`, there is no way to get `T2` **has to be** `T`.

Comment: How about sealing `Cat`?

Comment: @marsze I added an explanation of the required override; any other usage of covariance for the interface would do just as well, but that is mine as it is.

Comment: The problem here is that without restructuring the rest of C# as well, you would incur the runtime cost of checking either way. Let's say the interface allowed you to say "Only `Cat`, nothing else", what if I **first** do `Cat c = new Lion();` ?

Comment: You talk about "overriding", but I can only see a single type (`Shelter`). Also, why would you inherit from it in the first place, if you can simply go with `Shelter<Cat>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case like this, just remove the setter from the interface and use the concrete type (or infer it using `var` as in this example). After all, if the code "knows" for sure it is adding a cat, it probably also knows the shelter's concrete type.

```
interface IShelter<out AnimalType>
{
    AnimalType Contents { get; }
}

class Shelter<AnimalType> : IShelter<AnimalType>
{
    public Shelter(AnimalType animal)
    {
    }

    public void SetContents(AnimalType newContents)
    {
        Contents = newContents;
    }

    public AnimalType Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Usage
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var catshelter = new Shelter<Cat>(new Cat());
        catshelter.SetContents(new Cat());
        catshelter.SetContents(new Lion()); // Is disallowed by the compiler
    }
}
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JoaKPM)

The same pattern is followed by many CLR classes under `System.Collections.Generic`. Lots of classes implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which is covariant; but if you want to call the methods that allow you to add, you have to reference it as a concrete class such as `List<T>`.  Or if you really want to add via an interface you could use `IList<T>`. But in no case is there a single covariant interface that also allows you to add.

Comment: Neat. It still bothers me though to have a property with only a getter and an extra method for setting it. One could skip the setter altogether, as the animal is provided with the constructor (which would make it immutable), or also provide a `GetContents` method to make it more symmetric. Just a personal opinion.

Comment: I would change a lot of things (`TAnimal` instead of `AnimalType` for one) but the code is based on the OP's original example, modified only to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: Yeah my comment was primarily meant for OP rather than you. Great answer, esp. the explanations about how it's solved in the framework.

Comment: Indeed, I prefer using a setter as well. The seperate function was just so that it can accept object and cast it, as I had thought was necessary. Also, it was really helpful to point out that List<T> already does this with respect to IEnumerable<T>. I use those classes every day but somehow missed that fact.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible, because technically you want to have interface which is both [covariant and contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). Limitations of each type of variance are well explained here in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202349/1525637)

So, if you want to be able to set more derived type (e.g `TDerived : T`) to the `Contents` property, you should use contravariant interface:

```
public interface IShelter<in T>
{
    T Contents { set; }
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to be able to pass `Contents` to less derived type (e.g. `T : TBase`), you should stick with your current implementation:

```
public interface IShelter<out T>
{
    T Contents { get; }
}
```

Any other combination would result in possible runtime errors, that's why the compiler doesn't allow you to have an interface which is both co- and contravariant.

So, either use two distinct interfaces to achieve what you want, or rethink/polish your architecture around these types.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of so far would be using 2 separate interfaces for each of your concerns (`IShelter` and `ISpecificShelter`):

```
// this replaces IShelter<Animal>
public interface IShelter
{
    Animal Animal { get; set; }
}

// this replaces IShelter<SpecificAnimal>
public interface ISpecificShelter<AnimalType> : IShelter where AnimalType : Animal
{
    new AnimalType Animal { get; set; }
}

// implementation
public class Shelter<AnimalType> : ISpecificShelter<AnimalType> where AnimalType : Animal
{
    private Animal _animal;

    // explicit implementation, so the correct implementation is called depending on what interface is used
    Animal IShelter.Animal { get { return _animal; } set { _animal = value; } }
    AnimalType ISpecificShelter<AnimalType>.Animal { get { return (AnimalType)_animal; } set { _animal = value; } }

    public Shelter()
    { }
}
```

Usage:

```
// specific animal
ISpecificShelter<Cat> catShelter = new Shelter<Cat>();
catShelter.Animal = new Cat();
catShelter.Animal = new Lion(); // => compiler error!
Cat cat = catShelter.Animal;

// cast to general interface
IShelter shelter = catShelter;
Animal animal = shelter.Animal;
```

If you want to prevent instancing the class directly, but *only* work with the interfaces, you could implement a factory pattern:

```
public static class Shelter
{
    public static IShelter Create()
    {
        return new Implementation<Animal>();
    }

    public static IShelter Create(Animal animal)
    {
        return new Implementation<Animal>(animal);
    }

    public static ISpecificShelter<AnimalType> Create<AnimalType>() where AnimalType : Animal
    {
        return new Implementation<AnimalType>();
    }

    public static ISpecificShelter<AnimalType> Create<AnimalType>(AnimalType animal) where AnimalType : Animal
    {
        return new Implementation<AnimalType>(animal);
    }

    private class Implementation<AnimalType> : ISpecificShelter<AnimalType> where AnimalType : Animal
    {
        private Animal _animal;

        Animal IShelter.Animal { get { return _animal; } set { _animal = value; } }
        AnimalType ISpecificShelter<AnimalType>.Animal { get { return (AnimalType)_animal; } set { _animal = value; } }

        public Implementation()
        { }

        public Implementation(AnimalType animal)
        {
            _animal = animal;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var shelter = Shelter.Create();
shelter.Animal = new Lion();
// OR:
// var shelter = Shelter.Create(new Lion());
var animal = shelter.Animal;

var catShelter = Shelter.Create<Cat>();
catShelter.Animal = new Cat();
// OR:
// var catShelter = Shelter.Create(new Cat());
var cat = catShelter.Animal;

// cast is also possible:
shelter = (IShelter)catShelter;
```

It really depends on your specific use cases. You should provide more examples and information on what exactly you want to do and why.

Comment: Essentially your answer is the same as John Wu's; it's just that his is more succinct because he leaves out the ISpecificShelter and refers directly to Shelter. It's a shame you got downvoted despite being the first to post a correct solution.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I would have liked to know why. I am always open for positive critcism and suggestions to improve. I really like @JohnWu`s answer best, but I think my design isn't so bad either.