# C# covariance confusion

Tags: c#, covariance

The following is a code snippet about covariance in C#. I have some understanding about how to *apply* covariance, but there is some detailed technical stuff that I have hard time grasping.

```
using System;
namespace CovarianceExample
{
    interface IExtract<out T> { T Extract(); }
    class SampleClass<T> : IExtract<T>
    {
        private T data;
        public SampleClass(T data) {this.data = data;}   //ctor
        public T Extract()                               // Implementing interface
        {
            Console.WriteLine
                ("The type where the executing method is declared:\n{0}",
                this.GetType() );
            return this.data;
        }
    }
    class CovarianceExampleProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SampleClass<string> sampleClassOfString = new SampleClass<string>("This is a string");
            IExtract<Object> iExtract = sampleClassOfString;

            // IExtract<object>.Extract() mapes to IExtract<string>.Extract()?
            object obj = iExtract.Extract();
            Console.WriteLine(obj);                  
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

// Output:
// The type where the executing method is declared:
// CovarianceExample.SampleClass`1[System.String]
// This is a string
```

Invoking `IExtract<object>.Extract()` invokes `IExtract<string>.Extract()`, as evidenced by the output. While I kind of expected this behavior, I am not able to tell myself why it behaved the way it did.

`IExtract<object>` is `NOT` in the inheritance hierarchy containing `IExtract<string>`, except the fact that C# made `IExtract<string>` assignable to `IExtract<object`>. But `IExtract<string>` simply does **NOT** have a method named `Extract()` that it inherits from `IExtract<object>`, unlike the *normal* inheritance. It doesn't appear to make much sense to me at this time.

Would it be sensible to say that `IExtract<string>`'s **OWN** coincidentally (or by design) similarly named `Extract()` method hides `IExtract<object`>'s `Extract()` method? And that it is a kind of a hack? (Bad choice of word!)

Thanks

Comment: I think you have some major misunderstanding of how covariance works but it is hard for me to figure out precisely what it is.  **Covariance is not in any way inheritance**. Nor is it hiding.  Covariance is about *reference convertibility*

Comment: The underlying object is of type `SampleClass<string>` the interface just masks this, but the code is ran on the instance and the instance is `SampleClass<string>`. Remember interfaces do not run. They just show contracts of what a class can do.

Comment: @Eric, Thanks. But after converting a reference to SampleClass<string> to a reference of type IExtract<object>, aren't we supposed to do something with the new reference variable? and since the new reference variable is a variable of interface, which essentially is just a bunch of methods, that's why I don't understand the exhibited behavior.

Comment: @Sinatr This falls under Fair Use laws, not SO policy.  You can absolutely quote content from a book with the goal of understanding that content.  The OP is not taking credit for writing the code, nor are they profiting from it.   Fair use: "the doctrine that brief excerpts of copyright material may, under certain circumstances, **be quoted verbatim for purposes such as** criticism, news reporting, **teaching, and research**, without the need for permission from or payment to the copyright holder."

Comment: @Eric, so exactly what happens when I invoke IExtract<object>.Extract()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You definitely have some serious misunderstanding about how covariance works, but it's not 100% clear to me what it is.  Let me first say what interfaces are, and then we can go through your question line by line and point out all the misunderstandings.

Think of an interface as a collection of "slots", where each slot has a *contract*, and *contains* a method that fulfils that contract.  For example, if we have:

```
interface IFoo { Mammal X(Mammal y); }
```

then `IFoo` has a single slot, and that slot must contain a method that takes a mammal and returns a mammal.

When we implicitly or explicitly convert a reference to an interface type, we do not change the reference *in any way*. Rather, we *verify* that the referred-to type *already* has a valid slot table for that interface. So if we have:

```
class C : IFoo { 
  public Mammal X(Mammal y)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(y.HairColor);
    return new Giraffe();
  }
}
```

And later

```
C c = new C();
IFoo f = c;
```

Think of C as having a little table that says "if a C is converted to IFoo, C.X goes in the IFoo.X slot."

When we convert c to f, c and f have *exactly the same content*. They are *the same reference*. We have just *verified* that c is of a type that has a slot table compatible with IFoo.

Now let's go through your post.

> Invoking `IExtract<object>.Extract()` invokes `IExtract<string>.Extract()`, as evidenced by the output.

Let's crisp that up.

We have `sampleClassOfString` which implements `IExtract<string>`. Its type has a "slot table" that says "my `Extract` goes in the slot for `IExtract<string>.Extract`".

Now, when `sampleClassOfString` is converted to `IExtract<object>`, again, we have to make a check. Does `sampleClassOfString`'s type contain an interface slot table that is suitable for `IExtract<object>`? Yes it does: **we can use the existing table for `IExtract<string>` for that purpose**.

Why can we use it, even though those are two different types?  Because **all the contracts are still met**.

`IExtract<object>.Extract` has a contract: it is a method that takes nothing and returns `object`.  Well, the method that is in the `IExtract<string>.Extract` slot meets that contract; it takes nothing, and it returns a string, which is an object.

Since all the contracts are met, we can use the `IExtract<string>` slot table we've already got. The assignment succeeds, and all invocations will go through the `IExtract<string>` slot table.

> `IExtract<object>` is NOT in the inheritance hierarchy containing `IExtract<string>`

Correct.

> except the fact that C# made `IExtract<string>` assignable to `IExtract<object>`.

Don't confuse those two things; they are not the same.  *Inheritance* is the property that *a member of a base type is also a member of a derived type*.  *Assignment compatibility* is the property that an instance of one type may be assigned to a variable of another type.  Those are logically very different!

Yes, there is a connection, insofar that *derivation implies both assignment compatibility and inheritance*; if D is a derived type of base type B then an instance of D is assignable to a variable of type B, **and** all heritable members of B are members of D.

But don't confuse those two things; just because they are related does not mean they are the same. There are actually languages where they are different; that is, there are languages where inheritance is orthogonal to assignment compatibility. C# just is not one of them, and you're so used to a world where inheritance and assignment compatibility are so closely linked you've never learned to see them as separate. Start thinking of them as different things, because they are.

**Covariance is about extending the assignment compatibility relation to types which are not in inheritance hierarchies.** That's what covariance *means*; the assignment compatibility relation is *covariant* if *the relation is preserved across a mapping to a generic*. "An apple may be used where a fruit is needed; therefore a sequence of apples may be used where a sequence of fruits is needed" is *covariance*. The assignment compatibility relationship is *preserved across the mapping to sequences*.

> But `IExtract<string>` simply does NOT have a method named `Extract()` that it inherits from `IExtract<object>`

That's correct. There is no *inheritance* whatsoever between `IExtract<string>` and `IExtract<object>`. However, there is a *compatibility* relationship between them, because *any method* `Extract` which meets the contract of `IExtract<string>.Extract` is *also* a method that meets the contract of `IExtract<object>.Extract`. Therefore, the slot table of the former may be used in a situation requiring the latter.

> Would it be sensible to say that `IExtract<string>`'s OWN coincidentally (or by design) similarly named `Extract()` method hides `IExtract<object>`'s Extract() method?

Absolutely not. There is no hiding whatsoever. "Hiding" occurs when a derived type has a member of the same name as an inherited member of a base type, and the new member hides the old one *for the purposes of looking up names at compile time*.  Hiding is solely a compile-time name lookup concept; it has nothing whatsoever to do with how interfaces work at runtime.

> And that it is a kind of a hack?

**ABSOLUTELY NOT**.

I'm trying to not find the suggestion offensive, and mostly succeeding. :-)

This feature was carefully designed by experts; it is sound (modulo extending to existing unsoundnesses in C#, such as unsafe array covariance), and it was implemented with a great deal of caution and review. There is absolutely nothing whatsoever "hackish" about it.

> so exactly what happens when I invoke `IExtract<object>.Extract()`?

Logically, this is what happens:

When you convert the class reference to `IExtract<object>`, we verify that there is a slot table in the reference that is compatible with `IExtract<object>`.

When you invoke `Extract`, we look up the contents of the `Extract` slot in the slot table we have identified as compatible with `IExtract<object>`. Since that is the *same slot table* as the one the object already has for `IExtract<string>`, the same thing happens: the class's `Extract` method is in that slot, so it gets invoked.

In practice, the situation is a little more complicated than that; there is a bunch of gear in the invocation logic that is there to ensure good performance in common cases. But logically, you should think of it as finding a method in a table, and then invoking that method.

> Delegates can also be marked as covariant and contravariant. How does that work?

Logically, you can think of delegates as just interfaces that have a single method called "Invoke", and it follows from there. In practice, of course the mechanisms are somewhat different thanks to things like delegate composition, but perhaps now you can see how they might work.

> Where can I learn more?

This is a bit of a firehose:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+covariance

so I would start at the top:

[Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance/2202349#2202349)

If you want the history of the feature in C# 4.0, start here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

Note that this was written before we had settled on "in" and "out" as the keywords for contravariance and covariance.

A bunch more articles, in "newest first" chronological order, can be found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/

and a few here:

https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/

---

EXERCISE: Now that you know roughly how this works behind the scenes, what do you think this does?

```
interface IFrobber<out T> { T Frob(); }
class Animal { }
class Zebra: Animal { }
class Tiger: Animal { }
// Please never do this:
class Weird : IFrobber<Zebra>, IFrobber<Tiger>
{
  Zebra IFrobber<Zebra>.Frob() => new Zebra();
  Tiger IFrobber<Tiger>.Frob() => new Tiger();
}
…
IFrobber<Animal> weird = new Weird();
Console.WriteLine(weird.Frob());
```

? Give it some thought, and see if you can work out what happens.

Comment: Thanks, need some time to digest. And I apologize if the use of "hack" came across as offensive. I surely did not mean that.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr.: No worries; I was (mostly!) kidding. :)

Comment: @JohnSmithSr.: It is a little tricky to digest, I know. Once you've gotten through this screed, if you're hungry for more, I'll post some links to my blog where you can see how the feature evolved.

Comment: thank you again for a thorough explanation. The view on interface is indeed enlightening, and I have marked it as the answer. And thanks for those links you updated.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr.: You're welcome. I realized when I read your question that in 12 years of writing about this, I had never actually said how covariant interfaces *work* logically. I've said how virtual methods work, which is very similar, but not interfaces.

Comment: for the exercise, I get the fully qualified name of Zebra. I believe that is because IFrobber<zebra> is implemented first, and its contract IFrobber<zebra>.Frob() (no param, returns zebra, which is an animal) satisfies the contract of IFrobber<Animal> (no param, returns animal). I would get Tiger if the order of the Interfaces is reversed.

Comment: public modifiers generate errors for explicit implementation.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr.: Right, what is happening in this terrible situation is there are two interface slot tables that work, and the CLR is arbitrarily picking the one it finds first, and it just so happens that the CLR's slot table list is kept in the same order as the C# compiler generates it, and that is in the same order as the code appears in the sources. None of this is documented or guaranteed, and the CLR guidelines suggest that you never, ever do this; the CLR behaves poorly in situations where types can "unify" like this.